# Left and right arrow on banner are not displaying

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my live website link http://ibus.proserindustries.com/gauravresidency/index.html. I have uploaded all required CSS and JS files but it is not showing the left and right arrows when you hover the mouse on it. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: This is probably to do with fonts.  The content of your left-arrow is `\e5c4` and your right-arrow is `\e5c8`.  The font icon that this refers to is not loaded in the page header.

Comment: Add 'material-icons' font and 'CSS' in your template.

Comment: @Martiin : Can you please tell how to load that fonts ?

Comment: @AsfanShaikh : can you please elaborate what trying to says by you ?

Answer (score 0):

Paste inside `<head>` of your `html`, reference the location to your `font-awesome.min.css`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and in your call function

```
$(".category-wrapper").owlCarousel({
     items : 4,
     loop  : true,
     margin : 30,
     nav    : true,
     smartSpeed :900,
     navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
   });
```

Comment: Hello , which call function asking to put this code ?

Comment: just at the end of script like here i am calling the parent calss .category-wrapper in which my carosel(slider) is